# Selecting rows with duplicate values grouped

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have two tables that look something like this

Table Dog:

```
PK, color
1,  red
2,  yellow
3,  red
4,  red
5,  yellow
```

The dogs have toys.

Table toys

```
PK, FK, name
1,  2,  bowser
2,  2,  oscar
3,  3,  greg
4,  4,  alp
5,  4,  hanson
6,  5,  omar
7,  5,  herm
```

I need a query that selects the count of all yellow dogs that have more than one toy.

I was thinking somehting like:

```
Select count(*)
from toys t, dogs d
where t.fk = d.pk
and d.color = 'yellow'
group by t.fk    
having count(t.fk) > 1;
```

It should return 2. but it comes back with mutiple rows

Comment: You query is returning one row for each dog.  You can drop it in as a subquery and count the total rows returned.

Comment: Realised that the moment I posted. Fixed it and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(*)
from (
    select FK
    from Toys t
    inner join Dogs d on t.FK = d.PK
    where d."color" = 'yellow'
    group by FK
    having count(*) > 1
)
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f6784/10)